# Laravel Password reset causing Swift_TransportException error

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm building my first Laravel 6 project.  And just put my email settings in the .env file and it works on my local, I tested it with the password reset as it seemed to be the easiest way to generate an email.  Using the same email settings in the .env file on my live server, which is actually on the same server as the mail server referenced in the settings, when I try to do a password reset there, I get:

```
Swift_TransportException

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xx@xxx.com" using 3 possible authenticators. 
Authenticator CRAM-MD5 returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535
authentication failed (#5.7.1)". Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got
code "535", with message "535 authentication failed (#5.7.1)". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected 
response code 250 but got code "501", with message "501 malformed auth input (#5.5.4)".

vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php:191
```

Any idea what steps to take to debug the issue?  Thanks!

Comment: It clearly states that the env settings are wrong, sure you do not cache the configs?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else helped me out... for whatever reason due to a quirk in YAML, on my live server the MAIL_PASSWORD in .env needs to be in quotes, where it didn't matter on my local.